# How to choose delta parameter in Huber Loss function?

Tags: hyperparameter, huber

In Huber loss function, there is a hyperparameter (delta) to switch two error function. Currently, I am setting that value manually. But, I cannot decide which values are the best.
So, how to choose best parameter for Huber loss function using my custom model (I am using autoencoder model)? If you know, please guide me or send me links.

[image: huber loss equation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Huber loss will clip gradients to delta for residual (abs) values larger than delta.  You want that when some part of your data points poorly fit the model and you would like to limit their influence. Also, clipping the grads is a common way to make optimization stable (not necessarily with huber).

Set `delta` to the value of the residual for the data points you trust.

See how the derivative is a const for `abs(a)>delta`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def huber(a, delta):
  value = np.where(np.abs(a)<delta, .5*a**2, delta*(np.abs(a) - .5*delta))
  deriv = np.where(np.abs(a)<delta, a, np.sign(a)*delta)
  return value, deriv

h, d = huber(np.arange(-1, 1, .01), delta=0.2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(h, label='loss value')
ax.plot(d, label='loss derivative')
ax.grid(True)
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

As Alex Kreimer said you want to set $\delta$ as a measure of spread of the inliers. Most of the time (for example in R) it is done using the MADN (median absolute deviation about the median renormalized to be efficient at the Gaussian), the other possibility is to choose $\delta=1.35$ because it is what you would choose if you inliers are standard Gaussian, this is not data driven but it is a good start.

To get better results, I advise you to use Cross-Validation or other similar model selection methods to tune $\delta$ optimally.

Comment: If my inliers are standard gaussian, is there a reason to choose delta = 1.35?

Comment: I was a bit vague about this, in fact this is because before being used as a loss function for machine-learning, Huber loss is primarily used to compute the so-called Huber estimator which is a robust estimator of location (minimize over $\theta$ the sum of the huber loss beween the $X_i$'s and $\theta$) and in this framework, if your data comes from a Gaussian distribution, it has been shown that to be asymptotically efficient, you need $\delta\simeq 1.35$. See "robust statistics" by Huber for more info. Hence it is often a good starting value for $\delta$ even for more complicated problems.